# File seperation in Three.js using React Classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I've built a three.js application, but i'm struggling to figure out how i can put my functions in seperate files.

I got this mesh function that i would like to be in its own seperate file.

**My functions**

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.sceneSetup();
    this.addCustomSceneObjects();
    this.startAnimationLoop();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleWindowResize);
  }
```

**My Scene Function**

```
  sceneSetup = () => {
    const width = this.el.clientWidth;
    const height = this.el.clientHeight;

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
    this.camera.position.z = 5;
    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.el);
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
    this.el.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement); // mount using React ref
  };
```

**My Mesh Function** This is the function i'd like to have in a separate file.

```
  addCustomSceneObjects = () => {
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x156289, emissive: 0x072534, side: THREE.DoubleSide, flatShading: true});
    this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.scene.add(this.cube);
  }
```

Any suggestions on how i can do this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used three.js but your requirement is not a framework specific.

```
// addCustomSceneObjects.js
export default ({ scene, cube}) => {
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x156289, emissive: 
    0x072534, side: THREE.DoubleSide, flatShading: true});
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(this.cube);
  }
```

And then, use the extracted function like this

```
    // index.jsx

    import addCustomSceneObjects from './addCustomSceneObjects'

    componentDidMount() {
        //...
        addCustomSceneObjects({ scene: this.scene, cube: this.cube }) 

    }
```

Comment: This gives me the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cube' of undefined

Comment: i've been trying different solutions for a couple of hours, but cant seem to get it running. Do you have any more recommendations?

Comment: I got it working! forgot 'this' on the addCustomSceneObjects